# trouble loading json file in python3

Tags: python

I have tried separately to load a json file from both the command line and from a folder in vscode. I created a file called data.json in my Projects folder, navigated to that folder, and directly from the command line, I have typed the following:

```
>>> import json
>>> data = json.load(open("data.json"))
```

and I have received the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/json/__init__.py", line 296, in load
    parse_constant=parse_constant, object_pairs_hook=object_pairs_hook,**kw)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/json/__init__.py", line 348, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Comment: Please paste your JSON file here

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Is your JSON [valid](https://jsonlint.com/)?

Comment: @Saeed loads is for strings. What we have is a file.

Comment: @Jason Long try pasting your json data into a validator, this should point out the error. It will be easier to see there, than in a python traceback.

Comment: I am following along with a tutorial. The instructor has a json file that contains k,v pairs of dictionary terms and definitions. He instructed that I create an empty data.json file and then import json and load it into the data.json file I created. I have no idea where the json data is supposed to come from. i assumed it was imported.

Comment: https://jsonlint.com/ to help